# Outputting dynamic PHP code to insert into a dynamically created PHP page

Tags: php

Hey guys got a question on outputting a dynamic PHP block for a dynamically created PHP page. In my code I am looking for a string in an HTML page thats been uploaded. Once found I am replacing the string with a block of PHP code, the HTML page will be saved as a PHP page to be used on the project. So as I am looping through the HTML I am replacing the string with this ($i is replaced with the number in the loop so I can use them in my array.)

```
 $phpCodeNoLink = '<span id="Title'.$i.'"><?php echo $sl_result['.$i.'][2]; ?></span>
 <a href="editor.php?<?php echo "vfSID=" . $sl_result['.$i.'][0] . "&vfSection=2&vfSLink=" . $sl_result['.$i.'][4] . "&vfOrderID=" . $sl_result['.$i.'][5] . "&vfID=" . $vfID; ?>" target="_parent">
 <img src="images/btn_edit.gif" border="0" id="SL_editButton'.$i.'" class="editButton" />
 </a>';
```

The problem is it is not outputting what I need, example of what it should look like

```
 <span id="Title1"><?php echo $sl_result[1][2]; ?></span>
 <a href="editor.php?<?php echo "vfSID=" . $sl_result[1][0] . "&vfSection=2&vfSLink=" . $sl_result[1][4] . "&vfOrderID=" . $sl_result[1][5] . "&vfID=" . $vfID; ?>" target="_parent">
 <img src="images/btn_edit.gif" border="0" id="SL_editButton1" class="editButton" />
 </a>
```

This is what I get in the PHP page once it's generated

```
 <span id="Title0"><?php echo $sl_result[0][2]; ?></span>
 <a href="editor.php?&lt;?php%20echo%20%20" vfsid=" . $sl_result[0][0] . " .>" target="_parent"&gt;
 <img src="images/btn_edit.gif" border="0" class="editButton"></a>
```

The PHP tags are being replaced and I am missing a whole block of code. Am I missing something any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a dynamically created PHP page? PHP itself is used for creating pages dynamically, so wouldn't it make more sense to store the data that you need to create this page, and then use PHP to dynamically create the HTML whenever it's requested?

Comment: Well since you didn't look at what I'm doing thanks for the info what PHP does. If you had looked you would have seen the code is being place in a PHP file the file interacts with an editor giving the user the ability to edit said PHP page and the code will spit out HTML to use in email templates.

Comment: I fully understand what you're doing. I'm saying that it doesn't make sense to me to allow the user to create a dynamic PHP file when PHP by nature is dynamic. You're essentially doubling up on functionality. You should look into template engines that won't allow people to execute arbitrary code on your server (handlebars, mustache, jade, ejs, etc).

Comment: Users do not create dynamic PHP pages, I do they are templates that the user can edit (i.e. text field, text area, and images) to generate HTML content...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the PHP code was being parsed and removed by my inline CSS converter moving it above all the other parsing resolved it issue...